# How to dynamically add and remove views with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to create an interface for traversing tables in a relation database.  Each select represents a column.  If the column is a foreign key, a new select is added to the right.  This keeps happening for every foreign key that the user accesses.  The number of selects is dynamic.

I made a buggy implementation that has code that manually adds and removes select views.  I think it probably can be replaced with better Ember code (some kind of array object maybe?), I'm just not sure how to best use the framework for this problem.

Here's my JSBin http://jsbin.com/olefUMAr/3/edit

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Ember template" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.1.2/ember.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my_template">
    {{view fieldSelects}}
  </script>

  <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

var TemplatedViewController = Ember.Object.extend({
    templateFunction: null,
    viewArgs: null,
    viewBaseClass: Ember.View,
    view: function () {
        var controller = this;
        var viewArgs = this.get('viewArgs') || {};
        var args = {
            template: controller.get('templateFunction'),
            controller: controller
        };
        args = $.extend(viewArgs, args);
        return this.get('viewBaseClass').extend(args);
    }.property('templateFunction', 'viewArgs'),
    appendView: function (selector) {
        this.get('view').create().appendTo(selector);
    },
    appendViewToBody: function () {
        this.get('view').create().append();
    }
});

var DATA = {};
DATA.model_data = {
  "Book": {
    "fields": [
      "id",
      "title",
      "publication_year",
      "authors"
    ],
    "meta": {
      "id": {},
      "title": {},
      "publication_year": {},
      "authors": {
        "model": "Author"
      }
    }
  },
  "Author": {
    "fields": [
      "id",
      "first_name",
      "last_name",
      "books"
    ],
    "meta": {
      "id": {},
      "first_name": {},
      "last_name": {},
      "books": {
        "model": "Book"
      }
    }
  }
};

var Controller = TemplatedViewController.extend({
    view: function () {
        var controller = this;
        return this.get('viewBaseClass').extend({
            controller: controller,
            templateName: 'my_template'
        });
    }.property(),
    selectedFields: null,
    fieldSelects: function () {
        var filter = this;
        return Ember.ContainerView.extend({
            controller: this,
            childViews: function () {
                var that = this;
                var selectedFields = filter.get('selectedFields');

                var ret = [];
                var model = 'Book';
                selectedFields.forEach(function (item, index, enumerable) {
                    var selection = item;
                    if (model) {
                        var select = that.makeSelect(model, that.getPositionIndex(), selection, true).create();
                        ret.pushObject(select);
                        model = DATA.model_data[model].meta[selection].model;
                    }
                });

                return ret;
            }.property(),
            nextPositionIndex: 0,
            incrementPositionIndex: function () {
                this.set('nextPositionIndex', this.get('nextPositionIndex') + 1);
            },
            getPositionIndex: function () {
                var index = this.get('nextPositionIndex');
                this.incrementPositionIndex();
                return index;
            },
            setNextPositionIndex: function (newValue) {
                this.set('nextPositionIndex', newValue+1);
            },
            makeSelect: function (modelName, positionIndex, selection, isInitializing) {
                var view = this;
                return Ember.Select.extend({
                    positionIndex: positionIndex,
                    controller: filter,
                    content: DATA.model_data[modelName].fields,
                    prompt: '---------',
                    selection: selection || null,
                    selectionChanged: function () {
                        var field = this.get('selection');

                        // Remove child views after this one
                        var lastIndex = view.get('length') - 1;
                        if (lastIndex > this.get('positionIndex')) {
                            view.removeAt(this.get('positionIndex')+1, lastIndex-this.get('positionIndex'));
                            view.setNextPositionIndex(this.get('positionIndex'));
                        }

                        if (! isInitializing && DATA.model_data[modelName].meta[field].model) {
                            var relatedModel = DATA.model_data[modelName].meta[field].model;
                            view.pushObject(view.makeSelect(relatedModel, view.getPositionIndex()).create());
                        }

                        // Reset ``isInitializing`` after the first run
                        if (isInitializing) {
                            isInitializing = false;
                        }

                        var selectedFields = [];
                        view.get('childViews').forEach(function (item, index, enumerable) {
                            var childView = item;
                            var selection = childView.get('selection');
                            selectedFields.pushObject(selection);
                        });
                        filter.set('selectedFields', selectedFields);
                    }.observes('selection')
                });
            }
        });
    }.property()
});
var controller = Controller.create({
    selectedFields: ['authors', 'first_name']
});

$(function () {
    controller.appendView('#main');
});
```

Comment: Do you want to do some kind of dynamic grid?

Comment: A grid in what sense?  I'm looking for a better way to write the code that manages the ContainerView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Approach:

I would tackle this problem using an [Ember Component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/). 
I have used a component because it will be:

- Easily reusable
- The code is self contained, and has no external requirements on any of your other code.
- We can use plain javascript to create the view. Plain javascript should make the code flow easier to understand (because you don't have to know what Ember is doing with extended objects behind the scenes), and it will have less overhead.

### Demo:

I have created this [JSBin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ItiMeqOq/5/edit), of the code below.

### Usage

Add to your handlebars template:

```
{{select-filter-box data=model selected=selected}}
```

Create a `select-filter-box` tag and then bind your model to the `data` attribute, and your `selected` value array to the `selected` attribute.

The application:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  model: DATA.model_data,
  selected: ['Author','']
});

App.SelectFilterBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(''), // Blank template
  data: null,
  lastCount: 0,
  selected: [],
  selectedChanged: function(){

    // Properties required to build view
    var p = this.getProperties("elementId", "data", "lastCount", "selected");

    // Used to gain context of controller in on selected changed event
    var controller = this;

    // Check there is at least one property. I.e. the base model.
    var length = p.selected.length;
    if(length > 1){

      var currentModelName = p.selected[0];
      var type = {};

      // This function will return an existing select box or create new
      var getOrCreate = function(idx){

        // Determine the id of the select box
        var id = p.elementId + "_" + idx;

        // Try get the select box if it exists
        var select = $("#" + id); 
        if(select.length === 0){

          // Create select box
          select = $("<select id='" + id +"'></select>");

          // Action to take if select is changed. State is made available through evt.data
          select.on("change", { controller: controller, index: idx }, function(evt){

            // Restore the state
            var controller = evt.data.controller;
            var index = evt.data.index;
            var selected = controller.get("selected");

            // The selected field
            var fieldName = $(this).val();

            // Update the selected
            selected = selected.slice(0, index);
            selected.push(fieldName);
            controller.set("selected", selected);
          });

          // Add it to the component container
          $("#" + p.elementId).append(select);
        }
        return select;
      };

      // Add the options to the select box
      var populate = function(select){
        // Only populate the select box if it doesn't have the correct model
        if(select.data("type")==currentModelName)
          return;

        // Clear any existing options
        select.html("");

        // Get the field from the model
        var fields = p.data[currentModelName].fields;

        // Add default empty option
         select.append($("<option value=''>------</option>"));

        // Add the fields to the select box
        for(var f = 0; f < fields.length; f++)
          select.append($("<option>" + fields[f] + "</option>"));

        // Set the model type on the select
        select.data("type", currentModelName);
      };

      var setModelNameFromFieldName = function(fieldName){

        // Get the field type from current model meta
        type = p.data[currentModelName].meta[fieldName];

        // Set the current model
        currentModelName = (type !== undefined && type.model !== undefined) ? type.model : null;
      };

      // Remove any unneeded select boxes. I.e. where the number of selects exceed the selected length
       if(p.lastCount > length)
        for(var i=length; i < p.lastCount; i++)
          $("#" + p.elementId + "_" + i).remove();

      this.set("lastCount", length);

      // Loop through all of the selected, to build view
      for(var s = 1; s < length; s++)
      { 
        // Get or Create select box at index s
        var select = getOrCreate(s);

        // Populate the model fields to the selectbox, if required
        populate(select);

        // Current selected
        var field = p.selected[s];

        // Ensure correct value is selected
        select.val(field);

        // Set the model for next iteration
        setModelNameFromFieldName(field);

        if(s === length - 1 && type !== undefined && type.model !== undefined)
        {
          p.selected.push('');
          this.notifyPropertyChange("selected");
        }
      }      
    }    
  }.observes("selected"),

  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.selectedChanged();
  }
});
```

### How it works

The component takes the two parameters `model` and `selected` then binds an observer onto the `selected` property. Any time the selection is changed either through user interaction with the select boxes, or by the property bound to `selected` the view will be redetermined.

The code uses the following approach:

- Determine if the selection array (`selected`) is greater than 1. (Because the first value needs to be the base model).
- Loop round all the selected fields `i`, starting at index 1.

  1. Determine if select box `i` exists. If not create a select box.
  2. Determine if select box `i` has the right model fields based on the current populated model. If yes, do nothing, if not populate the fields.
  3. Set the current value of the select box.
  4. If we are the last select box and the field selected links to a model, then push a blank value onto the selection, to trigger next drop down.
- When a select box is created, an `onchange` handler is hooked up to update the `selected` value by slicing the `selected` array right of the current index and adding its own value. This will cause the view to change as required.
- A property `count` keeps track of the previous `selected`'s length, so if a change is made to a selection that decreases the current `selected` values length, then the unneeded select boxes can be removed.

The source code is commented, and I hope it is clear, if you have any questions of queries with how it works, feel free to ask, and I will try to explain it better.

### Your Model:

Having looked at your model, have you considered simplifying it to below? *I appreciate that you may not be able to, for other reasons beyond the scope of the question*. Just a thought.

```
DATA.model_data = {
  "Book": {
    "id": {},
    "title": {},
    "publication_year": {},
    "authors": { "model": "Author" }
  },
  "Author": {
    "id": {},
    "first_name": {},
    "last_name": {},
    "books": { "model": "Book" }
  }
};
```

So field names would be read off the object keys, and the value would be the meta data.

---

I hope you find this useful. Let me know if you have any questions, or issues.

---

### The Controller:

You can use any controller you want with this component. In my demo of the component I used Ember's built in `ApplicationController` for simplicity.

### Explaination of `notifyPropertyChange()`:

This is called because when we are inserting an new string into the `selected` array, using the `push` functionality of arrays.

I have used the `push` method because this is the most efficient way to add a new entry into an existing array.

While Ember does have a [`pushObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html#method_pushObject) method that is supposed to take care of the notification as well, I couldn't get it to honour this. So `this.notifyPropertyChange("selected");` tells Ember that we updated the array. *However I'm hoping that's not a dealbreaker.*

---

## Alternative to Ember Component - Implemented as a View

If you don't wish to use it in Component format, you could implement it as a view. It ultimately achieves the same goal, but this may be a more familiar design pattern to you.

[See this JSBin for implementation as a View](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eciYomIR/1/edit). *I won't include the full code here, because some of it is the same as above, you can see it in the JSBin*

### Usage:

Create an instance of `App.SelectFilterBoxView`, with a controller that has a `data` and `selected` property:

```
var myView = App.SelectFilterBoxView.create({
    controller: Ember.Object.create({
        data: DATA.model_data,
        selected: ['Author','']
    })
});
```

Then append the view as required, such as to `#main`.

```
myView.appendTo("#main");
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.  I don't understand how `App.ApplicationController` is connected to the component.  Is `App.ApplicationController` a name that Ember assumes?  And what is the function of the call to `notifyPropertyChange()`?  It may seem obvious from my code that I learned Ember in the early days before components and other features were invented and haven't caught up with all the changes yet.

Comment: Regarding the model, the reason for the redundancy is that I needed to keep the order of the fields.  My Python backend does this using an `OrderedDict` object, but JavaScript does not have a data structure like that as far as I know.

Comment: @hekevintran With regards to the `App.ApplicationController` you can use any controller you want. I have used the `ApplicationController` here because it is the most simple entry point into getting a basic Ember app running. I'll try find a better way to explain that. Will update the answer to explain the `notifyPropertyChange()` call. No worries, yeah Ember has changed quite a bit over time, it's fascinating to see the different techniques people you to accomplish tasks.

Comment: Couldn't you use `pushObject()` instead of `push()` to avoid calling `notifyPropertyChange()`?

Comment: @hekevintran If I'm honest I wasn't aware of `pushObject` for this purpose. I have tried that in my demo code, but it doesn't notify.

Comment: @hekevintran I have added an implementation as a Ember.View incase you want to stick with that familiarity of Ember. Hope it helps. Updated [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eciYomIR/1/edit).

Comment: Excellent implementation, Scott. Can you discuss what happens to the DOM and Ember objects when the extra select boxes are removed? Say I've lined up a chain of 3 books -> authors select boxes, and then I change the first 'authors' select to title instead; what precautions do you have to take to make sure you don't leek DOM elements or events.

Comment: @PatrickM Thanks. The implementation uses jQuery's [`Remove` function](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to handle the extra select boxes, that function takes care of cleaning up the events and data associated with the select box to be removed. The implementation also avoids creating a new select box if one already exists at the index, vs destroy and recreate. I see no reason in this code to think it will leek.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your code doesn't run, even after adding Ember as a library in your JSFiddle, but `ContainerView` is probably what you're looking for: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html as those views can be dynamically added/removed.

Comment: You might have experienced a loading problem.  The JSBin does run and it already includes Ember 1.1.2.  I am already using a ContainerView, but the problem is that the code that manages it is awkward and clumsy to use.

Answer (score 0):

`this.$().remove()` or `this.$().append()` are probably what you're looking for:

[Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_element).